# Remote Desktop freezes when using MS Access or opening shared folders for a specific user

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, microsoft-access, shared-folders

One of our users connects to an XP machine via Remote Desktop and logins into that machine as herself. She mainly works with MS Access in that Machine. However everything she clicks anything inside Access, her remote desktop session freezes and does not respond. If I login into the same machine using VNC I can see that the computer she is connecting to is not frozen, I can actually continue working in access if I use VNC. If she logins as another user in the remote machine, then everything works correctly. So the problem is only when she login as herself in the remote desktop sessions.

I already tried deleting her profile in the remote machine but that did not help.

The remote desktop session also freezes when she tries to open a network shared folder in the remote machine. She uses WinXP Pro and the remote machine is also XP Pro.

Thanks in advance!

**Update** If she uses another computer to remote into MS Access computer, then everything works fine. So I guess that make her local computer the culprit. She does use a shortcut to remote into the other machine, but we try logging in using start->accessories->remote desktop and we had the same problems. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: And this same user can work fine *without* Remote Desktop? What if you (using a different client machine) use her credentials? Is she using saved settings? (Such as some shortcut; if so, then maybe those saved settings have some local drive mapped, or maybe even some printer, which might not be used when using the non-saved other credentials?)

Comment: (As an aside: RDP is so fast as it's not sending pixels, but commands like "draw a button here". I could imagine that Access is using some specific controls that are supported by the server machine, but not by the client machine, and somehow the backwards compatibility fails. But that would not explain that different credentials work fine, and would also not explain the shared folder issue...)

Comment: Can you see any shared drives? Like maybe she's sharing her local drive with the remote computer? (Shouldn't yield any problems, but as it's really related to one set of credentials when used from one specific client, who knows... There's no old 3.5 inch drive making noises when she connects of clicks, right?)

Comment: No, there is nothing that Access does that somehow bypasses the native Windows graphics calls (which is what RDP receives from the remote computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to correct the issue by installing the newest version of RDP from [Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=12767).